# WSO2 EI | SOAP Envelope Exception

Tags: soap, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using WSO2 EI interacting with a SOAP Service. I have a weird case when SOAP Service returns HTTP 500, WSO2 returns the following exception. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:d176d8c6-57ff-4ee3-b5ca-e043602d6fec, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To><wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address></wsa:ReplyTo><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:992bea3f-16f0-49d3-91a2-1e03375bac9c</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:</faultcode><faultstring>First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found PhoneNumber</faultstring><detail><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception during creation of SOAP envelope structure
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Invoker.processInboundRequest(Axis2Invoker.java:3527)
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Invoker.invokeAxis2(Axis2Invoker.java:3101)
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:669)
at com.ibm.broker.axis2.TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.invokeAxis2(TomcatNodeRegistrationUtil.java:615)
```

Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found PhoneNumber
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.constructNode(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:305)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:252)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.createNextOMElement(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:234)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:249)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    at com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:2224)
    at com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:1924)
    at com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Invoker.processInboundRequest(Axis2Invoker.java:3521)
    ... 3 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after adding "soap11" to indicate that this request is a SOAP request.